# google analytics API vs Interface

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm wondering if anyone has come across a problem before as I cannot work out what the problem is. I'm pulling unsampled data from the API for behaviour on site and looking at Page Views (again on site this is also unsampled).

When the data is pulled however it the figures from the API are not matching the data shown in the interface. All other metrics match, however page views and unique page views make no resemblance.

Has anyone come across this before and is anyone able to advise?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the api request you are making what dates are you using, which api are you using ?

Comment: I'm just pulling through google sheets using the inbuilt tool. The request for page views is: ga:pageviews and ga:uniquePageviews. Dimensions is ga:landingPagePath

Comment: Which dates? if your doing anything under 48 hours old it may not be completed processing.  Also it could be an issue with sampling.

Comment: This is data from two weeks ago which we're running and the data is coming back unsampled in the report and unsampled on the interface. I've been informed it doesn't bee deduping and everything else matches barring page views and unique page views.

Comment: Sorry with out seeing the actual code there is no way I can tell you why its not matching then.  If its old data its not a processing issue, and if its not samples its not that.

Comment: See if you get the same data from [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)